# String .unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch

Tags: kotlin

I was solving a string conversion problem. At the compilation stage, the code throws an error: "unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline operator fun kotlin.text.StringBuilder /* = java.lang.StringBuilder */.set(index: Int, value: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.text".

An attempt to call the method set() directly did not lead to anything either. Here is my code. Could you please tell me what the problem is?

```
fun capitalize(text: String): List<String> 
{
    var even = text
    var odd = text
    for(i in 0 until text.length)
    {
        if (i%2==0)
        {
            even[i]=text[i].uppercase()
        }
        else
        {
            odd[i]=text[i].uppercase()
        }
    }
    return listOf(even, odd)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply replace some character in a `String` with another character like that. `String` is immutable - you cannot change the characters of an existing `String`. You can only create new, slightly different strings.

You should create `StringBuilder`s from `text`, which are mutable, so you can use the `even[i] = ...` syntax on `StringBuilder`s. At the end of the method, convert the `StringBuilder`s to `String`s.

```
fun capitalize(text: String): List<String>
{
    val even = StringBuilder(text)
    val odd = StringBuilder(text)
    for(i in text.indices)
    {
        if (i%2==0)
        {
            even[i] = text[i].uppercaseChar()
        }
        else
        {
            odd[i] = text[i].uppercaseChar()
        }
    }
    return listOf(even.toString(), odd.toString())
}
```

Notice also that the code uses `uppercaseChar` instead of `uppercase`. The former returns a `Char` instead of `String`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will remember this practice